# How to get all words containing certain characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DB with a varchar(250) field called ***description***. If I want to get all the records containing a certain character (let's say "x") I would use a query like this:

```
select * from mytable where description like '%X%';
```

What I need is an easy way to query the exact words within the description field that match the character "x", keeping in mind there may be more than 1 match per record.
So if my description field contains values like:

```
I like to play the xylophone
The x-ray fish lives in the Amazon
Jax and Dex are both six years old
```

The resultset would be:

```
xylophone
x-ray
Jax
Dex
six
```

I'm thinking the logic would be similar to how social media sites do trending topics with hashtags. I would like to be able to do this with a query, but a stored proc would also work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The only way I can think of to do this would be by splitting the data based on spaces and doing a `like` condition on each of the results in the set...that being said, it sounds like that would be absurdly slow.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing something like that. But I thought there might be an easier way. Slow is OK, as this is only a proof-of-concept prototype with limited data (maybe a couple hundred records)

Comment: This really sounds like something that should be handled on the client end; you could filter the results to only those that contain a certain number of matches, and then extra the words on the client side.

Comment: this would be easier in sql server - any chance you can use that?

Comment: no I have to use MySQL